# Simulating spam request?

Tags: apache-2.2, spam

I'm trying to test out some [blacklist directives](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/) that I've just implemented., Is there a way to simulate spam requests?

Comment: I presume you mean something a bit more formal than expressing your wish for the likes of Dr Oz on certain websites and leaving an email address behind? I'm not aware of a test service for this - one issue of course is that if you ask for it then its not actually spam, so any test results from something like this wouldn't be too valid anyway.

Comment: Basically, I'm just trying to veryify or test somehow that the specified directives are doing their job to some extent...

Answer (score 2):

The [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) and/or [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) utilities would probably be useful to you.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?